# Persist Joda-time's DateTime via Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jodatime

I'm using Jodatime in my Play app, but currently having to do a bunch of converting back and forth  from/to `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Time`.

Since jodatime is included in the Play distribution, I'm thinking there's probably a better way to do this. Is there any way I can make my Model fields `DateTime`s instead of `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Time` so the conversion is done automatically?  Is there another way of streamlining this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For Hibernate 3 add the following annotation to your date field:

```
@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
```

Hibernate will now do the dirty work for you.

(Make sure you have [joda-time-hibernate.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time-hibernate) in your classpath)

**UPDATE:**

For Hibernate 4 and 5 add the following annotation:

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
```

(Make sure you have [jadira-usertype-core.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.core) in your classpath)

Comment: I added that and imported `org.hibernate.annotations.Type` but got "Could not determine type for: org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalDate`". Anything else I need to set up?  Or maybe it's a problem with Play only using Hibernate via JPA rather than directly?

Comment: You should include the joda-time-hibernate jar in your classpath.

Comment: dropped the jar in `framework/lib`, restarted, and was able to get it working. Their website did trick me at first, the big 'get latest version' link is for joda-time, not joda-time-hibernate.

Comment: FYI, the CRUD module doesn't seem to support JodaTime as of now - https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/1268-crud-module-doesnt-support-jodatime

Comment: Is there some reason not to use `org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime`, since that is the data type that was being asked for? If you use this, it's also possible to get the field working with fixtures, since there is a binder for `DateTime` but not `LocalDate`.

Comment: Yes that would be a more accurate answer. Thanks for pointing that out. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @KeesdeKooter , the question asked for a JPA solution. Your answer uses @Type(...). I guess by this you mean org.hibernate.annotations.Type . Using this annotation creates a dependency on Hibernate. Do you know of a solution that uses the more general JPA instead of Hibernate?

Comment: @James and Abdull: true. This is a Hibernate only solution. But apparently good enough for the OP to accept the answer. Maybe we should rephrase the question as there is no out of the box solution for JPA as far as I can tell.

Comment: @James I corrected the answer in line with the edited question.

Comment: If you are in another timezone than UTC, be sure to specify this as a parameter to the `@Type`-annotation. I just got burned by this, with the times being persisted in the database being 2 hours earlier than they should have been, and appeared in the application.

Comment: While this is good for persistence and reading joda datetime fields, it still throws errors when trying to sort the results by that datetime field in JPA named queries. Do you or anyone know of a way around that?

Comment: You should turn to using jadira framework in case your Hibernate version is 4.x.

Comment: Thanks @russellhoff. I added this to the answer.

Comment: For anyone trying the above while using Java 7: Jadira usertype-core version 6 is only supported on Java 8 and higher. This results in a rather weird error (some class not found, similar to not having the dependency at all). Therefore you'll have to use verion 5 of the library with Java 7.

Answer (score 10):

1. Joda recommends to use the UserType libraries with Hibernate 4.0, the version of Hibernate bundled with Play 1.2.x (see: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/index.html).
2. The proper way to handle the dependency is using the `dependencies.yml` file, including a line like this:

   ```
   - org.jadira.usertype -> usertype.jodatime 2.0.1
   ```

Comment: I would suggest that you open a new question for this.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of putting the `@Type` annotation at each of your Joda properties you can add this in your jpa properties

```
#Hibernate config
jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true
```

and it should work just fine.

**ps.** [jadira-usertype-core.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.core) should be in your classpath.

Comment: This solution provides less reliance on Hibernate-specifc annotations. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

We should enable two jars in Hibernate 4 project:

- compile("joda-time:joda-time:2.8")
- compile("org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1")