# How to use joda time with JPA (eclipselink)?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink, jodatime

I tried to use the `DataTime` in my `entity` class. Adding `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` above the field, I got the error saying **"The persistent field or property for a Temporal type must be of type java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar or java.util.GregorianCalendar"**. I can introduce the conversion back and forth; using setters and getters as follows:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Calendar attendanceDate;

public DateTime getAttendanceDate() {
    return new DateTime(this.attendanceDate);
}

public void setAttendanceDate(DateTime attendanceDate) {
    this.attendanceDate = attendanceDate.toCalendar(Locale.getDefault());
}
```

but I hope `eclipselink` to do it for me. I have gone thro' [Persist Joda-time's DateTime via Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284098/persist-joda-times-datetime-via-jpa). The answer suggesting to use hibernate, but I have to use eclipselink. I can use the `DateTime` object in my entity class with DB representation as `BLOB`, but I need it as `Date`. Is there anything like `jodatime-eclipselink`? Or any other suggestion? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basic the link defines an EclipseLink Converter to convert from Joda DateTime to java.sql.Timestamp or Date.
You could use it, or define your own converter and use it through @Convert, @Converter in EclipseLink.

For DDL creation, the converter should define the initialize method and set the type on the mapping's field to java.sql.Timestamp.

Please log a bug (or vote for the existing one) on this in EclipseLink, we should have support for Joda.

Comment: Regarding the DDL creation, in my initialize method I have this: mapping.getField().setSqlType(java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP); However, the type that is created in my db is varchar(255). Any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: @kaciula I got it to work by adding this instead: `mapping.getField().setType(java.sql.Timestamp.class);`. HTH.

Answer (score 6):

I Try use joda-time-eclipselink-integration, but don't work, problably I made something wrong,

So I made more researchs and i found this link http://jcodehelp.blogspot.com.br/2011/12/persist-joda-datetime-with-eclipselink.html, they use @Converter annotation to convert the Joda Date Time.

I Try and works for me, I hope, works for you too.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do the same thing, and Googling around actually led me here. I was able to accomplish this using the `@Access` annotation. First, you annotate the class like this

```
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class MyClass
{
    ....
```

This provides field access to everything so you don't have to annotate the fields individually. Then you create a getter and setter for the JPA to use.

```
@Column(name="my_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
private Date getMyDateForDB()
{
    return myDate.toDate();
}

private void setMyDateForDB(Date myDateFromDB)
{
    myDate = new LocalDate(myDateFromDB);
}
```

The `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` tells JPA to persist and retrieve through these methods.

Finally, you'll want to mark your member variable as transient as follows

```
@Transient
private LocalDate myDate = null;
```

This stops JPA from trying to persist from the field as well.

That should accomplish what you're trying to do. It worked great for me.

Comment: How can we access `myDate` at service level (DAO)? It cannot have a mutator and an accessor (they are private as well for `myDateForDB`).

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. You can have a public getter and setter for the `LocalDate myDate`. Since the class is annotated with `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` JPA is not going to look at the getter and setter at all.

Answer (score 2):

Ahamed, you mentioned it wasn't working for you. Additionally you need to override the initialize method of the converter to define the desired field type:

```
@Override
public void initialize(DatabaseMapping mapping, Session session) {
    ((AbstractDirectMapping) mapping)
            .setFieldClassification(java.sql.Timestamp.class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The following is a working example based on the answers available in the topic**

Basically the easiest approach is to use EclipseLink `@Converter` for a `DateTime` field in your Entity.

The converter usage looks as follows:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Convert;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Converter;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

@Entity
public class YourEntity {

    @Converter(name = "dateTimeConverter", converterClass = your.package.to.JodaDateTimeConverter.class)
    @Convert("dateTimeConverter")
    private DateTime date;
```

And the converter itself:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping;
import org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.Converter;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class JodaDateTimeConverter implements Converter {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object convertDataValueToObjectValue(Object dataValue, Session session) {
        return dataValue == null ? null : new DateTime(dataValue);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertObjectValueToDataValue(Object objectValue, Session session) {
        return objectValue == null ? null : new Timestamp(((DateTime) objectValue).getMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(DatabaseMapping mapping, Session session) {
         // this method can be empty if you are not creating DB from Entity classes 
         mapping.getField().setType(java.sql.Timestamp.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

I am adding this for the purpose of easy *copy-and-paste* solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here
[joda-time-eclipselink-integration](http://code.google.com/p/joda-time-eclipselink-integration/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I found a jar file there and it has very less info. Am I supposed to use the only Converter class inside the jar file? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Still JPA will create a column as `BLOB` not as `DATE` :(

Comment: This still holds a snapshot. It does not appear to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Atais](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783577/how-to-use-joda-time-with-jpa-eclipselink/#answer-32632311) works well. Below an upgrade to it.

You can omit @converter annotation by registering it globally.
At persistance.xml in persitence-unit add:

```
<mapping-file>META-INF/xyz-orm.xml</mapping-file>
```

and file `META-INF/xyz-orm.xml` with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm" version="2.1">
    <converter class="pl.ds.wsc.storage.converter.JodaDateTimeConverter"/>
</entity-mappings>
```

If your config file is `META-INF/orm.xml` then you can omit even first step because it is default confing for all persitence units.