# EclipseLink DDL creating MySql DATETIME with fractional seconds

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I am using `EclipseLink 2.6.0` in my project together with `MySQL 5.6.19`.

Since `mysql 5.6.4` supports a fieldtype `DATETIME(6)` which allows to store a date with milliseconds precision in its value. Also `EclipseLink 2.6.0` says it supports this functionality.

---

**I am creating a database from my entities**. And I am not able to force it to create a proper field. In logs, during database creation I constantly see:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (..., DATE_FIELD DATETIME ...)
```

when, obviously, what I want is:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (..., DATE_FIELD DATETIME(6), ...)
```

---

**I tried using both, simple and annotated version:**

```
private java.util.Date date1;

@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date date2;
```

but the outcome is always the same. So how does the Eclipselink supports this? How to determine the proper field type?

Comment: have you seen/tried using  @Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME(6)") ?

Comment: well.. that works as expected. I know the annotation, I do not know why I did not think about it :-) Thanks.

Comment: using `columnDefinition` breaks portability and always is the worst possible approach - your **actual** solution **should** be `@Column(length=6)`

Comment: @specializt you can provide this as a full answer if you like. It works just the same for now, but I understand the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [specializt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/351861/specializt) for the tip, easy solution:

```
@Column(length=6)
private Date myTime;
```

works also with YodaTime converter ([description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783577/how-to-use-joda-time-with-jpa-eclipselink/32632311#32632311))

```
@Column(length=6)
@Converter(name = "dateTimeConverter", converterClass = pl.ds.eemediation.storage.entities.converters.JodaDateTimeConverter.class)
@Convert("dateTimeConverter")
private DateTime date;
```