# JPA 2.0 and @Type annotation in Play Framework

Tags: jpa-2.0, jodatime, playframework-2.0

I want to try out Joda Time with Play Framework 2.0. So I have this class called **Release**:

```
@Entity
public class CommunicationLog extends Model {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7846963755390952329L;

@Id
public int pk;

public Task taskRef;

public String comment;

@Type(type = "org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
public DateTime createdDate;

public Person personRef;

}
```

In this post ( [Persist Joda-time's DateTime via Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284098/persist-joda-times-datetime-via-jpa) ), I have read to use **joda-time-hibernate**. So I add this to my dependencies with SBT and it downloads the jar file and adds it to my classpath:

```
"joda-time" % "joda-time-hibernate" % "1.3"
```

But the problem remains that the **@Type** cannot be resolved. I need to add also org.hibernate.annotations and hibernate core to my classpath? Why is this not part of JPA 2.0? Or do I miss something else in my project?

**EDIT 2012-05-07 : SOLVED WITH**

It works when I add the following dependencies:

```
"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "3.5.6-Final",
"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-annotations" % "3.5.6-Final",
"joda-time" % "joda-time-hibernate" % "1.3"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you must add **org.hibernate.annotations** to your classpath.
`@Type` is part of Hibernate logic (Custom UserType), it's not a logic of JPA.
So you must mix JPA annotations with Hibernate annotations