# Joda Time and hibernate 4

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jodatime, spring-data

I am using hibernate 4 with joda time and spring data jpa. Spring data provides annotations

```
@CreadedOn
@LastModifiedOn
```

i am trying to use these two annotations.Below is a snapshot of my pojo

```
@Entity
@Table(name="restaurant")
@Audited
public class Restaurant {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String restaurantName;

@CreatedDate
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
 // @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threetenbp.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime createdOn;

@LastModifiedDate
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
 // @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.threetenbp.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime modifiedOn;
}
```

as per the instructions provided [user types jodatime](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html),i have annotated my properties with `@Type` .but still no luck.Everytime i use the `@Type` annotation and deploy it i get a error on my server

> SEVERE: Error listenerStart

Full stack trace is below

```
    Jan 15, 2014 11:40:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive G:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\base-spr
ing-data-jpa.war
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:00 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJa
rFile
INFO: validateJarFile(G:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\base-spring-data-jpa\WEB-I
NF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, sect
ion 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further detail
s.
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:05 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:05 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.7.Final}
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:05 AM org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:05 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.Connect
ionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.c
onnection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:06 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/base-spring-data-jpa] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:06 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearRefer
encesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/base-spring-data-jpa] registered the JDBC driver [
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was
stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistere
d.
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:06 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearRefer
encesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/base-spring-data-jpa] appears to have started a th
read named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This
 is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory G:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\docs
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory G:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\exampl
es
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:06 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory G:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\host-m
anager
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory G:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\manage
r
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory G:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\ROOT
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:07 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jan 15, 2014 11:40:07 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6648 ms
```

Since yesterday i am trying to get these two work but unable to do so.Can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem.Below is my pom Dependencies and repository

```
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.27</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

```
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persist Joda-time's DateTime via Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284098/persist-joda-times-datetime-via-hibernate)

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque:Thanx for the update :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need to use @Type annotation. Just add following jpa property:

```
entityManagerFactory.getJpaPropertyMap().put("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes", "true");
```

Also I think that you've missed jadira dependecy:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
  <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.CR10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i cant thank u enough.i wish i could vote ur answer more than once.It worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

If you use gradle and spring boot with annotation based configuration you can use @jakub-kubrynski advice by

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:3.2.0.GA'
}
```

**application.properties**

```
#Hibernate config
spring.jpa.properties.jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes=true
```

Comment: Testing with Spring Boot 1.3.1 and jadira 5.0.0.GA gives me `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.registerTypeOverride(Lorg/hibernate/usertype/UserType;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;`

Comment: I can't find anything definitive on this right now, but I'm pretty sure this is because 5.0.0.GA should work with Hibernate 5.x and version 4.0.0.GA with Hibernate 4.x.