# how to resolve Joda date/time type `org.joda.time.DateTime` not supported by default

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an existing web-app and unfortunately the 'time' fields in the DB are not converted to zulu time. Instead we are using `org.joda.time.DateTime` as our datetime and timezone encapsulator.

I am in the process of updating from hibernate 4.3.7.Final to 5.3.20.Final

Also, we are letting hibernate manage the translation of these DateTime objects to/from the db using

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime lastUpdatedTimestamp; // <-- org.joda.time.DateTime
```

Running this on hibernate 5 gives this error:

```
10:22:11,463 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Joda date/time type `org.joda.time.DateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda" to enable handling (through reference chain: org.<company>.crs.model.PermissionEntity["lastUpdatedTimestamp"])
```

wondering why this would work in hibernate 4 before the update to 5?
I am using joda-time version 2.1 but have been able to reproduce the issue in 2.9.7

I have also looked and found this thread [Persist Joda-time's DateTime via Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284098/persist-joda-times-datetime-via-hibernate) but, their solution was to convert to Joda's `LocalDateTime` which unless I am mistaken does not support time zones which are needed for my use case.

Edit: I have added the requested module, and I still get the same error. I have tested this with Joda versions: 2.10.10, 2.9.7, and 2.1

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I believe 'Joda date/time type `org.joda.time.DateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda" to enable handling' is prettly clear. What help did you expect from us?

Comment: I am confused as to why it worked with nothing special in hibernate 4 but not 5?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with Hibernate, it's thrown by Jackson

Comment: This is probably just me being stupid, but, I added the Jackson module as an mvn dependency and I still get the same error.

Comment: There's an `XxxModule` class provided by that dependency. You need to register the module by calling `objectMapper.registerModule(new XxxModule())`

Comment: Resolution: Thank you crizzis!
I needed to only have 1 version of jackson-datatype-joda in my dependencies.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you been able to solve it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to register the JodaModule on your ObjectMapper, like this:

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule;

 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .registerModule(new JodaModule())
    ...;
```

Prior to Jackson 2.12, you wouldn't get the error you're seeing because Jackson would default to using the BeanSerializer if it encountered a Joda object. Here's the code added in 2.12 that now raises an error instead:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/2.13/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/BeanUtil.java#L288

Comment: In my case of older app it was the best to call registerModule() using Spring settings in XML file (with MethodInvokingFactoryBean).

Comment: I still get the error even after registering the Joda module.

`objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule())`

 I also confirmed that there is only one ObjectMapper reference in the entire code base.

Comment: how to solve this in spring MVC . object mapper is not something which we create in our code in this case