# Quarkus and Hibernate (Value too long for column)

Tags: hibernate, jodatime, quarkus

I am using Quarkus and Hibernate. However, I am having the following error:

(Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev): org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Value too long for column "APPOINTMENT"

I am writing a class similar to this. I added @Lob above DateTime, but I am not sure if it is the right approach. Thanks.

```
@Entity
public class NameOfTheClass expands PanacheEntityBase {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Integer id;
     @Lob
     private DateTime appointment;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist Joda-time's DateTime via Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284098/persist-joda-times-datetime-via-hibernate)

Comment: After adding this dependency: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>. Quarkus does not work: ERROR [io.qua.run.boo.StartupActionImpl] (Quarkus Main Thread) Error running Quarkus: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException